# GSEventCreateKeyEvent

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I'm new to jailbreak programming.
When executing the following code:

```
if ($GSEventCreateKeyEvent != NULL) {
    string = CFStringCreateWithCharacters(kCFAllocatorDefault, &unicode, 1);
    event0 = (*$GSEventCreateKeyEvent)(10, point, string, string, nil, 0, 0, 1);
    event1 = (*$GSEventCreateKeyEvent)(11, point, string, string, nil, 0, 0, 1);
} else if ($GSCreateSyntheticKeyEvent != NULL) {
    event0 = (*$GSCreateSyntheticKeyEvent)(unicode, YES, YES);
    GSEventRecord *record(_GSEventGetGSEventRecord(event0));
    record->type = GSEventTypeKeyDown;
} else return;
```

After declering both the GSEventCreateKeyEvent and GSCreateSyntheticKeyEvent.
Both of the method are not identify and the function returns.
What do I miss?
Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your question.

To inject key events, you can use

`int hid_inject_text(const char * utf8_text);`

from the hid-support project at http://code.google.com/p/hid-support/

Comment: Hi mringwal, Thank you for the respons hid-support looks great, but I tryed both hid_inject_text and: hid_inject_key_down(c, 0x01); hid_inject_key_up(c); with no success. What do I miss? Thank you.

Comment: Weird. What device/os did you try? Was a text field active and the on-screen keyboard shown?